# I am getting error at timeouts() and windows() methods as "The method window() is undefined for the type WebDriver.Options"

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am using 
`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` and `driver.manage().window().maximize();` methods. But I am getting error at `timeouts()` and `windows()` as "The method window() is undefined for the type WebDriver.Options"same error message for `timeouts()` method also. Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance,
Manasa.

Comment: Show your `import` statement and `driver` declaration

Comment: Poor practice of writing the question.

Answer (score 0):

You must have used incorrect Class Imports -

driver.manage().timeouts() and 
driver.manage().window().maximize()

Should work as it is.

Refer -
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

for further clarification, please post your code.